# Wikipedia API parse action only returning "other languages" section

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to display a random Wikipedia article. I have an ajax request for a random page ID and an inner ajax request to parse the text of that page ID. I get a random page ID every time, but when I try to display it with the inner ajax request, all that is displayed is the "other languages" section.

I am using [the call specified by the Wikipedia API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&pageid=56705), but I'm not getting the same result that is shown on that page. Any insight?

Here's my function:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //document.ready
  $('#random-btn').click(function() { //random-btn click
    $.ajax ({ //ajax random page 
      url: "http://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php",
      jsonp: "callback",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        action: "query",
        format: "json",
        list: "random",
      },
      success: function (randomPage) { //random page success
        var randomID = randomPage.query.random[0].id.toString();
        console.log(randomID);
        $.ajax ({ //ajax display given page
          url: "http://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&pageid=367435",
          jsonp: "callback",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          data: {
            action: "parse",
            format: "json",
            pageids: randomID,
          },
          success: function (jsonObject) { //display success
            var displayText = jsonObject.parse.text["*"];
            $('#display').html(displayText);
          } //display success
        }) //ajax display given page
      } //random page success
    }) //ajax random page 
  }) //random-btn click
}) //document.ready
```

Comment: In your inner AJAX request you already added the data to the URL — as well as `pageid` (which is 367435). Try removing the query strings from the URL and use the `data` array in your request method to add data to it. Besides, in the URL you use `&pageid` whilst the variable in your data array will use `&pageids`.

Comment: ahh thank you, good catch, i copied the url from the api sandbox and used it to populate the data array, just forgot to erase the end of the url, woops haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all this also by using generator with [extracts](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) property in one request. Check parameters for more options.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#random-btn').click(function () {
        $('#display').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                action: 'query',
                format: 'json',
                generator: 'random',
                prop: 'extracts',
                grnnamespace: 0,
                explaintext: true
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var pages = result.query.pages;
                var page = pages[Object.keys(pages)[0]];
                $('#display').append($('<h2>').text(page.title));
                $('#display').append($('<p>').text(page.extract));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id="random-btn">Get random</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```